# Make fields mandatory based on other field value - Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm trying to create a behavior in Jira that checks whether a field ("Call #1") is not empty and if so it makes two other fields required.
it was written in ScriptRunner (Groovy)

```
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FieldBehaviours
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FormField
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def optionsManager = ComponentAccessor.getOptionsManager()

// Get the Call #1 Field
FormField call1 = getFieldByName('Call #1') 

// Get the Role #1 Field
FormField role1 = getFieldByName('Role #1') 

// Get the Call result #1 Field
FormField callResult1 = getFieldByName('Call result #1') 

if (call1.getValue() != null)
{
   role1.setRequired(true)   
   callResult1.setRequired(true)
}
```

I'm not sure why but it's making both "Role #1" and "result #1" fields mandatory from the beginning even though the "Call #1" is empty. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

You are so close.

If you write behaviour, you should consider two things.
One of them is the Initializer script, which runs when the screen first loaded.
The other one is script for the field. (In your case, the `Call #1` field); which runs when the field's value changed.

Also, you should remove the `required` field at start of your script.

So the following script should be placed both at Initializer script and the field's script:

```
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FieldBehaviours
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FormField
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def optionsManager = ComponentAccessor.getOptionsManager()

// Get the Call #1 Field
def call1 = getFieldByName('Call #1') 

// Get the Role #1 Field
def role1 = getFieldByName('Role #1') 

// Get the Call result #1 Field
def callResult1 = getFieldByName('Call result #1') 

role1.required = false   
callResult1.required = false

// Also if you log the call1's value, you can check the actual value from the Jira's log
def call1Value = call1.getValue()
log.warn(call1Value)

if (call1Value != null || !call1Value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) // and if it is a String field, check the emptiness
{
   role1.required = true
   callResult1.required = true
}
```

Comment: well, it looks good but for some reason, it makes both "role1" &  "callResult1" fields required when the form just opened. 
I am wondering maybe it has something to do with the fact that "call1" is a user picker field? (it uses to pick the Jira user who made the call, like the assignee field).

Comment: What is the log output when you log call1Value? If they are required, it means the call1Value is not null. It may have a default value or the User picker may return an empty list or something like that. Can you add the log output to the question? Also, before logging, you may want to add another log.warn line like `log.warn("---> " + call1Value)`. You can trace it from <atlassian-home>/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jiria.log

Comment: I'm not sure I got <atlassian-home>/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jiria.log . 
I'm using an old version of Jira software. 
I think that if I will have a way to check the Userpicker custom filed "Call #1" I will be able to set the other field required.
I'm not sure how else I can debug the logs from the ScriptRunner Behaviors screen.